# Check if multidimensional object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional object. Depending on its content (empty or not empty) I want to execute different functions.
So I'm trying to check if it's empty:

```
arr = [
  [],
  [],
  []
];

Object.size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0,
    key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

var size = Object.size(arr);

if (size > 0) {
  alert("NOT empty!")
} else {
  alert("empty...")
}
```

In my example it says `NOT empty!`, though it is empty (well, kind of. There are several empty objects).

So how can I determine if it consists of empty objects?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn2xth1n/2/).

Comment: `arr.length` would do pretty good in your case here...

Comment: Is your question specific to arrays?

Comment: Second `alert` is not ending...hint...`aler`, also it makes sense to return not empty when obviously contains 3 empty elements which count.

Comment: @jAndy I think OP needs to give a better, probably recursive definition of 'empty'. He probably considers [[]] empty as well even though [[]].length == 1

Comment: The result is true, it isn't empty, you have 3 empty arrays inside it.

Comment: Obligatory warning: adding static methods to `Object` that have generic names is a bad idea. Just write a function. Or give it a name less likely to conflict with other code/future JS versions.

Comment: Why don't us iterate you array and check the length of your inner arrays ? If there are all empty, you array is empty ? + you do not have a **multidimensional object** you have a multidimensional **array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the array

```js
    var arr = [
      [],
      [],
      []
    ];
    
    Object.size = function(obj) {
      var size = 0,
        key;
      for (key in obj) {
        if (obj[key].length != 0) size++;
      }
      return size;
    };
    
    var size = Object.size(arr);
    
    if (size > 0)  alert("NOT empty!")
     
    else           alert("empty...")
```

fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zn2xth1n/1/)

Comment: Can you make the example in your answer runnable?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it runs in fiddle example

Comment: That's wonderful... but links rot. Please be nice to future readers and make the example in your answer runnable.

Answer (score 7):

[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is all you need

```
var hasValues = arr.some( function (a) { return a.length });
```

or you could use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
var isEmpty = arr.every( function (a) { return !a.length });
```

Answer (score 6):

If you consider **arrays** as empty as long as they only contain **empty slots** or **arrays which are empty** themselves, use a recursive function:

```js
function isEmpty(array) {
  return Array.isArray(array) && (array.length == 0 || array.every(isEmpty));
}

// Examples:
console.log(isEmpty([[], [[]]]));    // true
console.log(isEmpty([,,]));          // true
console.log(isEmpty([undefined]));   // false
console.log(isEmpty([null]));        // false
console.log(isEmpty(['']));          // false
console.log(isEmpty([0]));           // false
console.log(isEmpty([{}]));          // false
console.log(isEmpty({}));            // false
```

Comment: Be aware that depending on how big or deep the array is, you might hit a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the array

```
var arr = [ [], [], [] ];

var flattenedArray = arr.flat(1);

console.log(flattenedArray.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @ÖzgürErsil's answer but works for objects and Arrays:

```
let onlyEmpties = arg => {
  let hasNoEntries = item => {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === "[object Array]") {
      return item.length === 0;
    } else {
      return Object.keys(item).length === 0;
    }
  };

  let isEmpty = hasNoEntries(arg);
  return isEmpty || 
    (arg.every ?
      arg.every(hasNoEntries) :
      Object.keys(arg).every(hasNoEntries)
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try the following. It gives the result how many element are not empty in the array. Try the plunker link give below.

```
arr = [
            [],
            [],
            []
        ];
        var i, len=0;
        for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            //console.log(arr[i].length);
            if(arr[i].length!=0){
                len++;
            }
        }
        console.log("Array have "+ len +" Element");
```

[See the demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/leriK8eTJYNdp6QsZaEB?p=preview)